# Starting lightdm in wsl2 in VcXsrv

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was able to start the lightdm and manager and greeter in a wsl2 debian in VcXsrv setting. When first starting the debian bash terminal and first starting the VcXsrv instance it appears to work fine. I can login at the greeter and be taken to gnome shell desktop.

```
/etc/init.d/dbus start
/etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

However, when I logout, gnome shell doesn't actually quit and the greeter appears as overlayed on top of the gnome shell... it appears gnome shell does not actually quit (the processes are still alive checking with ps).

The only way to start fresh is to exit the VcXsrv instance AND stop the LxssManager instance and restart it.

1. Why is gnome-shell staying alive after logout?
2. I would like to switch to xfce desktop. (I was already able to start xfce using xfce4-session).

Settings for /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[Seat:*]
type=xremote
xserver-share=true
xserver-hostname=192.168.0.116
xserver-display-number=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where `192.168.0.116` came from, but try replacing it with `$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null)` or `$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0`